# How does VPNService work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, ip, android

I am trying to understand how does VPNService work? I am using tPacketCapture on my android, which a packet sniffer that uses VPNService.

Thanks to tPacketCapture application I can capture the communication between my phone and my server. The IP address of my phone is **`192.168.10.177`** but VPNService attributes a new private IP **`10.8.0.1`** address to my phone, which will be used to transmit data to the server.

When I visualized the .pcap file that I got, I noticed that some data are transmitted using my phone's original IP address **`192.168.10.177`** and others were sent using the private IP address that the VPN created **`10.8.0.1`**.

As you can see in [Traffic.pcap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deOpM.png) the first 7 packets are sent with the VPN's private IP address and the 8th one is sent with the original IP address of my android device.

My question is, why isn't all the traffic sent to the server using the private Ip address?

Comment: Look up "split tunnelling".  Some VPNs are configured to send all traffic to the VPN server, and then Internet requests go out from there.  Some VPNs are configured to only send traffic specifically meant for the internal network around the VPN server, and other traffic is handled normally.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Thank you a lot for your response. I'm thinking that this might also be coming from the VPN itself. We build the VPN connection using our local network which uses the address 192.168.10.177 for my phone. so maybe the VPNService is sending those packets using the original IP address og my phone. Does this seem logical to you?